# Is it possible to prevent `set -x` from reporting on the commands ran from a trap? Or have a custom prefix for `set -v`?

Tags: bash

My motivation - I would like to echo commands before evaluation and the actually executed commands, but with a custom prefix.

As far as I know `PS4` is for `set -x`, but there is nothing for `set -v` and the only way to emulate `set -v` with a custom prefix is through `trap 'echo "##[command]$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG`.

However, the command in the `trap` is intercepted by `set -x`, which is not good.

For example:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ env -i HOME="$HOME" USER="$USER" bash --noprofile --norc
bash-5.1$ PS4='[debug] ' ; trap 'echo "[verbose] $BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG ; set -x
[verbose] set -x
bash-5.1$ ls -1 | head -2 | xargs echo
[[debug] echo '[verbose] ls -1'
[verbose] ls -1
[[debug] echo '[verbose] head -2'
[verbose] head -2
[debug] head -2
[[debug] echo '[verbose] xargs echo'
[verbose] xargs echo
[debug] xargs echo
[debug] ls -1
1 1.txt
bash-5.1$
```

So the problematic output is:

```
[[debug] echo '[verbose] ls -1'
[[debug] echo '[verbose] head -2'
[[debug] echo '[verbose] xargs echo'
```

So, my question - is there a solution to this? Is it possible to "hide" the command in the `trap` from `set -x`? Or maybe there is a prompt dedicated to `set -v`?

Comment: Surprised you don't get _command not found_ errors from `ls`, `head`, &c with `env -i` and nothing setting `PATH` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the logs of the `echo` you don't want to show up in xtrace logs somewhere they won't be seen. If you haven't modified `BASH_XTRACEFD`, that means redirecting stderr.

```
trap '{ echo "[verbose] $BASH_COMMAND"; } 2>/dev/null' DEBUG
```

It doesn't work if you apply the redirection to the `echo` itself, but if you apply it to the block the `echo` is in, you get the desired effect.

---

Applying the above change, behavior is more appropriate:

```
$ ls -1 | head -2 | xargs echo
[verbose] ls -1
[verbose] head -2
[debug] ls -1
[verbose] xargs echo
[debug] head -2
[debug] xargs echo
```